# How to check null values in dataframe and assign status to new column using pyspark

Tags: pandas

I have a python code to check null value in dataframe and query on column values. then assign the status to new columns as below:

```py
df['StatusCode'] = 0
df.loc[(df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)].query('value_max<value_current')).index.tolist(),'StatusCode'] = "Fail, Null value and Value_max is less than Value_current"
df.loc[(df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)].query('value_max>=value_current')).index.tolist(),'StatusCode'] = "Fail, Null value in column "
df.loc[(df[~df.isnull().any(axis=1)].query('value_max<value_current')).index.tolist(),'StatusCode'] = "Fail, Value_max is less than value_current "
df.loc[(df[~df.isnull().any(axis=1)].query('value_max>=value_current')).index.tolist(),'StatusCode'] = "Pass, All good" 

df[['StatusCode','Comments']] = pd.DataFrame(df['StatusCode'].str.split(", ").values.tolist())
```

Comment: and the issue is?

Comment: I am not able to convert this code to spark with error: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: I think it is pandas df not spark df